# How to change user agent when Tor ip changes in Scrapy

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I use Tor and Privoxy with TorIpChanger to change ip after a random number of items_scraped. And it is working fine. I would like to change user-agent as well, when ip changes.
I am a bit confused about the way to go to achieve this. I have had a look at scrapy_useragents and similar solutions looking for inspiration, without a lot of success for now. This is what i'm trying to do, based on https://github.com/khpeek/scraper-compose/ and https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/extensions.html

**extensions.py**

```
class TorRenewIdentity(object):

    def __init__(self, crawler, item_count, user_agents):
        self.crawler = crawler
        self.item_count = self.randomize(item_count)    # Randomize the item count to confound traffic analysis
        self._item_count = item_count                   # Also remember the given item count for future randomizations
        self.items_scraped = 0
        self.user_agents = user_agents

        # Connect the extension object to signals
        self.crawler.signals.connect(self.item_scraped, signal=signals.item_scraped)

    @staticmethod
    def randomize(item_count, min_factor=0.5, max_factor=1.5):
        '''Randomize the number of items scraped before changing identity. (A similar technique is applied to Scrapy's DOWNLOAD_DELAY setting).'''
        
        randomized_item_count = random.randint(int(min_factor*item_count), int(max_factor*item_count))
        
        logger.info("The crawler will scrape the following (randomized) number of items before changing identity (again): {}".format(randomized_item_count))
        
        return randomized_item_count

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        if not crawler.settings.getbool('TOR_RENEW_IDENTITY_ENABLED'):
            raise NotConfigured

        item_count = crawler.settings.getint('TOR_ITEMS_TO_SCRAPE_PER_IDENTITY', 10)
        user_agents = crawler.settings['USER_AGENT']

        return cls(crawler=crawler, item_count=item_count, user_agents=user_agents)          # Instantiate the extension object

    def item_scraped(self, item, spider):
        '''When item_count items are scraped, pause the engine and change IP address.'''

        self.items_scraped += 1
        if self.items_scraped == self.item_count:
            logger.info("Scraped {item_count} items. Pausing engine while changing identity...".format(item_count=self.item_count))

            self.crawler.engine.pause()
            
            ip_changer.get_new_ip()                        # Change IP address with toripchanger https://github.com/DusanMadar/TorIpChanger
            self.items_scraped = 0                                  # Reset the counter
            self.item_count = self.randomize(self._item_count)      # Generate a new random number of items to scrape before changing identity again
            
            # Get new user agent from list
            if self.user_agents:
                new_user_agent = random.choice(self.user_agents)
                
                logger.info('Load {} user_agents from settings. New user agent is {}.'.format(
                len(self.user_agents) if self.user_agents else 0, new_user_agent))
                
            # Change user agent here ?
            # For next self.item_count items
            # headers.setdefault('User-Agent', new_user_agent)
            #
            
            self.crawler.engine.unpause()
```

**settings.py**

```
USER_AGENT = [
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/16.0.912.36 Safari/535.7',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.12; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0'
]

# Enable or disable spider middlewares
# See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html
#SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {
#    'scrapydevua.middlewares.ScrapydevuaSpiderMiddleware': 543,
#}

# Enable or disable downloader middlewares
# See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html
#DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
#    'scrapydevua.middlewares.ScrapydevuaDownloaderMiddleware': 543,
#}

EXTENSIONS = {
   'scrapydevua.extensions.TorRenewIdentity': 1,
}
```